# Media Queries not fitting correctly on mobile version

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Currently doing a redesign of my current site and am using it as a learning tool, as it will be the first project using media queries.

I've got the header looking fine in browser and on my mobile but at the moment horizontal scrolling with extra white padding either side, I've tried reducing the width of the main content but still has the same result except it just adds white padding

http://www.adamhuxtable.com/demos/ah/v1/index.html

Was just wondering if there was something I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any tips/advice

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't give your `.container` a width. Let it be `auto`. Its a bit difficult to say what's next. Could you provide a Fiddle?

Oh, I forgot: I also removed the `position: absolute` of your `#circle`.